# can I implement Google Pay Button on iOS device using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-pay

I am using this [Pay Flutter Package](https://pub.dev/packages/pay) , and I use this code below to show Google Pay Button

```
GooglePayButton(
  paymentConfiguration: PaymentConfiguration.fromJsonString(
      defaultGooglePayConfigString),
  paymentItems: _paymentItems,
  type: GooglePayButtonType.buy,
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
  onPaymentResult: onGooglePayResult,
  loadingIndicator: const Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  ),
)
```

but the button won't show on iOS devices, only on Android. as far I know I can run the code below to know whether the button can be shown or not

```
late final Pay _payClient;
_payClient = Pay(
  {
    PayProvider.google_pay: PaymentConfiguration.fromJsonString(defaultGooglePayPaymentConfiguration),
  },   

final canPay = await _payClient.userCanPay(PayProvider.google_pay);
```

When I run the code above on real iOS device, the `canPay` will return `false`.

my question is, is it possible the `canPay` will be `true` on iOS devices if certain condition has been met?

Comment: Hey there! Just curious – any particular reason for featuring the Google Play button on an iOS device? 

Comment: @OvidiuUşvat no, I just get the requirement to implement it on iOS, but if it doesnt make sense then I will only provide Apple Pay :)

Comment: The `pay` plugin is not specific to Google Pay. It supports Apple Pay on iOS and Google Pay on Android (see the platform support section in the docs – https://pub.dev/packages/pay#platform-support).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pay` plugin is not specific to Google Pay. It supports Apple Pay on iOS and Google Pay on Android (see the platform [support section](https://pub.dev/packages/pay#platform-support) in the docs).

As Ovidiu hints, Google Pay is not supported on iOS. Your requirements are only yours, but if you are looking for a platform-native payment facilitator, Apple Pay is certainly worth considering. The documentation includes an [example](https://pub.dev/packages/pay#example) with the `ApplePayButton`.